# Getting an error when trying to execute pentaho job

Tags: java, batch-file, pentaho-spoon, error-log

I am trying to execute a Pentaho job with a .bat file, but I keep getting an error when I execute it through the.bat file.
First, I spoke with the I.T. assistant from my company and we saw that the antivirus was blocking the script but, even after he gave me the encessary permissions, it still shows the same error.
When I execute it through Spoon, it works fine. This problem only pertains to executing it through the script.

My Pentaho Version is:
[image: this].

The error that I'm experiencing is:

**Error:**

```
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe

D:\Pentaho_Data_Integration\data-integration>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64;/bin" "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\lib\endorsed;D:\Pentaho_Data_Integration\data-integration\system\karaf\lib\endorsed" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\launcher.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen -initialDir "C:\Users\weslley.nascimento\Desktop"\ /file:"C:\TEMP\CARDOSO_E_CORREA_POSTAGEM_TAG\CARDOSO_JOB.kjb" /level:Basic 
09:25:31,990 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
09:25:38,725 INFO  [KarafInstance] 
*******************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 1 at D:\Pentaho_Data_Integration\data-integratio ***
***   n\.\system\karaf\caches\kitchen\data-1                                ***
*** Karaf Port:8802                                                         ***
*** OSGI Service Port:9051                                                  ***
*******************************************************************************
2021/07/05 09:25:43 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Log básico
2021/07/05 09:25:43 - Kitchen - Start of run.
09:25:56,006 ERROR [BootFeaturesInstaller] Error installing boot features
org.apache.karaf.features.internal.util.MultiException: Error:
    Error downloading mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr/2.1.16
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.<init>(MavenDownloadManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:72)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:457)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:452)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:393)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.handlePrerequisites(Deployer.java:1116)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1062)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Error downloading mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr/2.1.16
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr:jar:2.1.16: [Could not find artifact org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr:jar:2.1.16 in karaf-system (file:D:/Pentaho_Data_Integration/data-integration/system/karaf/system/)]
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.configureIOException(AetherBasedResolver.java:803)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:774)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:657)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:598)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:565)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:52)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:60)
        ... 7 more
        Suppressed: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr:jar:2.1.16 in karaf-system (file:D:/Pentaho_Data_Integration/data-integration/system/karaf/system/)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:368)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:642)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:489)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
            at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
            at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767)
            ... 12 more
    Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr:jar:2.1.16
        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413)
        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767)
        ... 12 more
```

This is the .bat file:

```
@echo off
 
TITLE Test Job
SET currentdir=%~dp0
SET kitchen=D:\Pentaho_Data_Integration\data-integration\Kitchen.bat
SET logfile="%currentdir%log.txt"

echo. >> %logfile%
echo. >> %logfile%


"%kitchen%" /file:"C:\TEMP\TEST\TEST_JOB.kjb" /level:Basic >> %logfile%
# level: Error Minimal Basic Detailed Debug Rowlevel
```

Any help would be appreciated and I'm open to answer any more pending questions that are necessary to solve my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: So you have a bat file that runs another bat file that then runs a jar?

Comment: yes, it was one of the ways I found to schedule a Job in Windows